# Sorting SQL Query By Date Column

Tags: sql, oracle, date, where-clause

I'm working on a project with a db that contains a date column for patient visits in the format of %m-%d-yyyy and need to sort so that it only pulls the rows where that date is within the last two weeks. I've tried a few different functions of convert, to_date, and can't seem to get anything to work.

I'm still very new to SQL and I don't know if this is a special case because I'm working with an oracle db

Not the full code, because it has dozens of queries and multiple joins (would that affect the date syntax?) but this is the format I'm trying for...

```
create table "Visits"

insert into "Visits" (
    'John Doe',
    '5/24/2021',
    'Story about the visit',
    'More room for story if needed')

select
    "User_Name",
    "Visit_Date",
    "Visit_Narrative",
    "Visit_Narrative_Overflow"
    from "Visits"
where "Visits"."Visit_Date" >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 14
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement for your table(s); the DML (`INSERT`) statements for some sample data that replicates your issue; the full text of the error message; and your expected output for that sample data.

Comment: It responds with [SQLCODE: <-359>:<SQL Function (function stored procedure) not found>]. It's important to note, it's being pulled into excel

Comment: What is the definition of `"Visits"."Visit_Date"`?

Comment: "Visits"."Visit_Date" is the column where the date of the patient's visit is stored, e.g. 5/24/2021. Because I'm only able to access the DB through an OBDC connection on Excel it doesn't provide me with anymore information

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working on a project with a db that contains a date column for patient visits in the format of %m-%d-yyyy

No, you don't have it in the format `mm.dd.yyyy`. A `DATE` data type value is stored within the database as a binary value in 7-bytes (representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second) and this has **no** format.

> need to sort so that it only pulls the rows where that date is within the last two weeks.

You want a `WHERE` filter:

If you want to have the values that happened in the last 14 days then `TRUNC`ate the current date back to midnight and subtract 14 days:

```sql
SELECT visit_date
FROM   patient
WHERE  visit_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '14' DAY
```

or

```sql
SELECT visit_date
FROM   patient
WHERE  visit_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 14
```

*(or subtract 13 if you want today and 13 days before today.)*

If you want it after Monday of last week then `TRUNC`ate to the start of the `I`SO `W`eek (which is always a Monday) and subtract 7 days:

```sql
SELECT visit_date
FROM   patient
WHERE  visit_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. With those I keep experiencing a -359 error, I think because like you said, it's not a real date format - the db just has it as a string of that date (although it's not the date the row was created) i'll add the full snipet to give a better idea

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out based on an answer from another forum (linked below);
it appears that my original to_date() was incomplete without a second and operator in my where clause. This code is working perfectly

```
select
    "User_Name",
    "Visit_Date",
    "Visit_Narrative",
    "Visit_Narrative_Overflow"
    from "SQLUser"."Visits"
   where "SQLUser"."Visits"."Visit_Date" >= to_date('5/10/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    and "SQLUser"."Visits"."Visit_Date" < to_date('5/24/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```